# How to remedy "no usable data in this plot to autoscale axis range" in Gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot, color-mapping

I'm trying to create a color plot of some data. I'm using a script file that I've used before successfully on a similar data set. The data set that worked had equal distant Y data points and this new set I am trying to plot has increasing distance between the Y points and a larger Y range. That is the only significant difference I can find. When I try to plot it, however, I get the error:

> "FlareA.scr", line 32: warning: No usable data in this plot to auto-scale axis range
>   "FlareA.scr", line 32: z axis range undefined or overflow

This is what my script file looks like:

```
set yrange [100:116]
set xrange [1:4]
set xtics 0,.5,24
set xlabel "Hour"
set ylabel "Altitude (km)"
set cbrange [4:6]
set cblabel "Density"
set palette maxcolors 256
set palette defined ( 0 "#000090",\
                      1 "#000fff",\
                      2 "#0090ff",\
                      3 "#0fffee",\
                      4 "#90ff70",\
                      5 "#ffee00",\
                      6 "#ff7000",\
                      7 "#ee0000",\
                      8 "#7f0000")

set terminal pngcairo enhanced font 'Verdana,13' size 1242,960
set output "FlareA_F.png"

set view map
set pm3d map
unset key

set title "Ne density"
splot "FlareA_F.txt" using (($1-1133)*24):2:3 with pm3d
```

And here is a sample of what my data file looks like

```
3133.04175  100.  5.06040859  4.51200008  4.91599989 -0.0170000009
3133.04175  104.  5.1217308  4.56899977  4.97900009  0.639999986
3133.04175  108.  5.12965775  4.62200022  4.96799994  1.14699996
3133.04175  112.  5.1110301  4.66200018  4.92000008  1.53999996
3133.04175  116.  5.07975054  4.68400002  4.85599995  1.85800004
3133.04175  124.  5.04357147  4.73799992  4.74499989  2.41700006
3133.04175  132.  5.08901501  4.84299994  4.71700001  2.9849999
3133.04175  140.  5.16615963  4.94799995  4.73799992  3.50399995
3133.04175  148.  5.23499727  5.0250001  4.75899982  3.92700005
3133.04175  156.  5.28483677  5.06400013  4.7670002  4.26300001
3133.04175  164.  5.3220067  5.07399988  4.7579999  4.53200006
3133.04175  172.  5.35366201  5.05900002  4.73400021  4.75600004
3133.04175  180.  5.38500214  5.0170002  4.69500017  4.94999981
3133.04175  188.  5.42543507  4.94700003  4.63899994  5.12799978
3133.04175  196.  5.47803974  4.8499999  4.56400013  5.28599977
3133.04175  204.  5.5400548  4.73000002  4.46899986  5.421
3133.04175  220.  5.65969706  4.46400023  4.2420001  5.61299992
3133.04175  236.  5.74195671  4.20300007  4.00199986  5.72100019
3133.04175  252.  5.7819829  3.96700001  3.76699996  5.77099991
3133.04175  268.  5.79048967  3.75500011  3.53999996  5.78399992
3133.04175  284.  5.77621031  3.56399989  3.32200003  5.77199984
3133.04175  300.  5.74792337  3.39100003  3.11199999  5.74499989
3133.04175  316.  5.70914888  3.23399997  2.91000009  5.70699978
3133.04175  332.  5.66364908  3.08999991  2.71300006  5.66200018
3133.04175  348.  5.61530399  2.95600009  2.52200007  5.61399984
3133.04175  364.  5.56505632  2.82999992  2.33500004  5.56400013
3133.04175  380.  5.51387072  2.70900011  2.15300012  5.51300001
3133.04175  396.  5.46272516  2.59100008  1.97399998  5.46199989
3133.04175  412.  5.41161013  2.47600007  1.79999995  5.41099977
3133.04175  428.  5.36251354  2.36100006  1.63  5.36199999
3133.04175  444.  5.31343365  2.24600005  1.46399999  5.3130002
3133.04175  476.  5.2203083  2.01600003  1.14900005  5.21999979
3133.04175  508.  5.13122034  1.78799999  0.856999993  5.13100004
3133.04175  548.  5.02414703  1.50999999  0.523000002  5.02400017
3133.04175  600.  4.89508963  1.171  0.135000005  4.89499998
3133.04175  700.  4.67703915  0.598999977 -0.5  4.67700005
3133.04175  800.  4.50301886  0.119999997 -1.02499998  4.50299978

3133.04517  100.  5.05211449  4.5079999  4.90600014 -0.0299999993
3133.04517  104.  5.11557293  4.56500006  4.97200012  0.626999974
3133.04517  108.  5.12465668  4.6170001  4.96299982  1.13499999
3133.04517  112.  5.10667324  4.65700006  4.91599989  1.53100002
3133.04517  116.  5.07654285  4.6789999  4.85400009  1.84899998
3133.04517  124.  5.03957796  4.73199987  4.74300003  2.40700006
3133.04517  132.  5.08425999  4.83699989  4.71400023  2.9749999
3133.04517  140.  5.16121674  4.94199991  4.73500013  3.49499989
3133.04517  148.  5.23118496  5.02099991  4.75600004  3.92000008
3133.04517  156.  5.28195047  5.06099987  4.76499987  4.2579999
3133.04517  164.  5.32028008  5.07200003  4.75699997  4.53000021
3133.04517  172.  5.35239553  5.05700016  4.73400021  4.75500011
3133.04517  180.  5.38494158  5.01599979  4.69500017  4.95100021
3133.04517  188.  5.42560816  4.9460001  4.63899994  5.12900019
3133.04517  196.  5.47885752  4.84800005  4.56400013  5.28800011
3133.04517  204.  5.54133701  4.72900009  4.46799994  5.42299986
3133.04517  220.  5.66049337  4.46299982  4.24100018  5.61399984
3133.04517  236.  5.74193859  4.20300007  4.00099993  5.72100019
3133.04517  252.  5.78100395  3.96799994  3.7650001  5.76999998
3133.04517  268.  5.78853273  3.75699997  3.53900003  5.78200006
3133.04517  284.  5.77425098  3.56800008  3.3210001  5.76999998
3133.04517  300.  5.74496603  3.39599991  3.11199999  5.7420001
3133.04517  316.  5.7051878  3.24000001  2.90899992  5.70300007
3133.04517  332.  5.66067648  3.09599996  2.71300006  5.65899992
3133.04517  348.  5.61133194  2.96300006  2.52200007  5.61000013
3133.04517  364.  5.5610795  2.83699989  2.33599997  5.55999994
3133.04517  380.  5.50989151  2.71700001  2.15300012  5.50899982
3133.04517  396.  5.45874453  2.5999999  1.97500002  5.45800018
```

Any help or suggestions on how to remedy my issue would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Your x-values are outside the range you define. The defined range is `[1:4]`, whereas your sample data has x-values of `48000`.

If for some later data points the x-values are inside the specified range, it may also happen, that the increasing y-values are placed such, that the y-values are outside. Remove the `set xrange` and `set yrange` settings to debug this.

Comment: This applied (($1-1133)*24) when plotting my X-values puts them all between the defined range. I've used this same script on files with the exact same x values and it worked perfectly. I'll double check it though.

Comment: Nope. Your values in col. 1 are 3133, so 3133-1133=2000 and 2000*24=48000 is a little bit larger than 4. Just remove the x/yrange commands and see what gnuplot says what your ranges are.

Comment: Well, the data you posted obviously is outside of the specified range. Possibly, since you have increasing y-values, it could also happen, that for the data value, where the x-values are inside the specified range, the gap in the y-values is so big, that you have no values inside. To debug, remove the `set xrange` and the `set xtics` lines (or also the `set yrange` part).

Comment: God I feel like an idiot. This is what happens when you look at the same stuff for hours at a time. Thanks for being a fresh set of eyes. 

I'm going to disappear in shame now. :D